# How to update css theme file in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am confused on where to edit WordPress themes. I am new to WordPress and have a custom theme which main `style.css` file just imports the style for this theme like this:

```
@import url('assets/stylesheets/app.css');
```

I read that it is recommended to make a new child theme, but I don't see the need for that in my case, since I would like to almost completely change the css of the theme, so there is no need to keep the original theme files. Since, I tried to modify the file `'assets/stylesheets/app.css'` I couldn't see any changes in the browser. Can I edit the styles there, or I need to do it in the `WP admin dashboard` somewhere?
I would like to build my scripts with gulp, which I set up like this:

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var sass          = require('gulp-sass');
var include       = require('gulp-include');
var watch         = require('gulp-watch');
var batch         = require('gulp-batch');
var sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var prefix        = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var connect       = require('gulp-connect');
var browserify    = require('gulp-browserify');
var livereload    = require('gulp-livereload');
var browsersync   = require('browser-sync');

var config = {
  srcDir: './assets',
  styles: {
    src: '/scss/app.scss',
    dest: '/stylesheets',
    includePaths: [
      'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'
    ],
    prefix: ["last 2 versions", "> 1%", "ie 9"]
  },
  scripts: {
    src: '/js/app.js',
    dest: '/js'
  },
  img: {
    src: '/images/**/*',
    dest: '/images'
  }
};

var srcDir = './src',
    destDir = './build';

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.srcDir + config.styles.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: config.styles.includePaths,
      sourceMap: true,
      outFile: config.srcDir + config.styles.dest + '/app.css',
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }))
    .pipe(prefix(config.styles.prefix))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.srcDir + config.styles.dest))
    .pipe(browsersync.reload({ stream: true }));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(config.srcDir + config.scripts.src)
      .pipe(browserify({
        insertGlobals : true,
        debug : !gulp.env.production
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.srcDir + config.scripts.dest))
});

gulp.task('include', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.srcDir + config.img.src)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.srcDir + config.img.dest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch(config.srcDir + config.styles.src, ['styles']);

    // Watch .js files
    gulp.watch(config.srcDir + config.scripts.src, ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

So, not sure how can I do it utilizing gulp. Where can I change the theme without creating the child theme?

Answer (score 0):

Where does the import of "app.css" happen - at the beginning or at the end of the "style.css" file? If it's at the beginning, the changed rules in "app.css"  might be overwritten by the following "style.css" rules.

Comment: Yes, and that file is importing app.css ```@import url('assets/stylesheets/app.css');```

Comment: sorry, I found out what was the mistake, since I cloned the repository in the database the url was still the one from the original repository, so it was pulling the css stylesheets from a live server, when I changed that it was working. Thank you for you help anyway!